# Borland C++ - using OLE to open RTF file using Word

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, ole

I'm new with Embarcadero C++Builder, VCL and OLE. What I'm trying to do is open an RTF file using OLE, but I'm getting an exception:

> Bad variable type

when executing this line:

```
wordDoc = wordDoc.OleFunction( "open", file );
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is my code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include <tchar.h>

#include <System.hpp>
#include <oleauto.h>
#include <sysvari.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();

        UnicodeString file( "C:\\TempFiles\\Test.rtf" );

        Variant wordApp = Variant::CreateObject( "word.application" );
        wordApp.OlePropertySet( "Visible", Variant( false ) );

        Variant wordDoc = wordApp.OlePropertyGet( "documents" );
        wordDoc = wordDoc.OleFunction( "open", file );

        //Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
        //Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a [`UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString) in the 2nd parameter of [`Variant::OleFunction()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant.OleFunction) when calling Word's [`Open()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/documents-open-method-word) function.

Internally, `OleFunction()` converts the input parameters to [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant) values (rather than [`OleVariant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.OleVariant)), and then passes them as-is to [`IDispatch::Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx).

`Variant` is compatible with OLE only when it holds OLE-compatible data.  `UnicodeString` is specific to Delphi/C++Builder and unknown to OLE, so it is not OLE-compatible.

When a `Variant` is assigned a `UnicodeString` value, its `VType` field is set to `varUString` (0x0102), and its payload is a pointer to the `UnicodeString`'s internal data with its `refCnt` field incremented (the `Variant` will decrement the `refCnt` when destroyed).

OLE is complaining about that unsupported `VType` value when your `UnicodeString`-turned-`Variant` is passed to `IDispatch::Invoke()`.

To fix the error, you need to instead pass a `WideString` to `OleFunction()`.  `WideString` is a wrapper for an [OLE `BSTR` string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx).  When a `Variant` is assigned a `WideString` value, its `VType` field is set to `varOleStr` (0x0008, aka `VT_BSTR` in OLE), and its payload is a proper `BSTR` pointer that is a copy of the `WideString` data (the `Variant` will free the `BSTR` when destroyed).

So, you need to either:

- change your `file` variable to `WideString`:

  ```
  WideString file( L"C:\\TempFiles\\Test.rtf" );
  ```
- keep your `file` variable as `UnicodeString`, but convert it to `WideString` when passing it to `OleFunction()`:

  ```
  wordDoc = wordDoc.OleFunction( L"open", WideString(file) );
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and detailed explanation.